# Android: How to run a callback right after setText() is rendered

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I want to display some text in an `EditText` and do some work right away after the text is displayed. I have the following code in my `onCreate()` method:

```
this.editor.setText(text, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Work that needs to be done right after the text is displayed
    }
}, 1000);
```

This works OK, but I want to minimize the delay between `setText()` rendering and the work being done-- a 1s delay is unacceptable. However, if I change the delay to 0ms or 1ms, then the work is done before the text gets rendered.

I could keep typing in numbers to search for the perfect delay time that would execute my code just after the text was rendered, but that seems very tedious/imprecise. Is there a better way to tell Android to run a callback right after that happens? Thanks.

**edit:** Here are two things I've tried that didn't work. For bonus points, it would be very helpful if you could explain to me why these didn't work.

**Using `Handler.post`**

`new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(r)` also runs `r` before the text finishes rendering. I thought `setText` adds rendering code to the queue, so shouldn't `post(r)` being called after that add `r` after the rendering code?

**Using `View.post`**

`this.editor.post(r)` didn't work either, `r` is still called before the text is rendered.

Comment: why you didn't use TextWatcher???

Comment: @hamid_c Not sure, but I think that runs before the UI is updated, no?

Comment: Exactly, `afterTextChanged(...)` will do the trick for you.

Comment: i don't know about that, but i think you can try

Comment: @Wizard, I just tried `afterTextChanged`. It doesn't help because the callback is still called before the text is rendered.

Comment: This seems to be a very uncommon requirement, are you taking a screen shot or why is it important to do something after the text was rendered on the screen? Maybe there is another way to achieve the same effect.

Comment: @Henry Is it? I'm trying to load the text of a source code file for display, then syntax highlight it. Since syntax highlighting can take a long time for large files, I want to first display the uncolored text then update the display when the text has been colored.

Comment: In that case, why can't you start the coloring before the text is fully rendered?

Comment: @Henry A different approach, I suppose, would be to start coloring on a new thread after `setText()` rather than slowing things down even further by waiting for the text to render. Thanks, I hadn't thought of that.

Comment: @pskink Based on experimental evidence? When I click on a large file, the app freezes for a second, then displays the colored text, rather than displaying the uncolored text, freezing, then coloring it.

Comment: what if you run your code with postDelayed in TextWatcher's afterTextChanged method for something about 100ms?

Comment: @pskink It is not freezing on `setText()`, but the work after `setText()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I initially wanted to delay the work because it was CPU-intensive. I realized the solution was to spin up a new thread for the work, rather than post it to the UI thread.

Answer (score 1):

Use this it would hlp

```
mSongNameTextView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can assign a [`TextWatcher`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) to your `EditText`.

A `TextWatcher` is basically a listener that listens for changes to the text (before, during and after) in the `EditText`.

It can be implemented as follows:

```
EditText et;
et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // Work that needs to be done right after the text is displayed
    }
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
}
```

So when you set the text explicitly, this listener should be called and after the text is changed, the `// Work that needs to be done right after the text is displayed` code will be run.

Comment: EdmDroid, thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, `afterTextChanged` does not help: the callback is still being invoked before anything is drawn.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ViewTreeObserver` as below:

```
yourView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            // do your work here. This call back will be called after view is rendered.
            yourView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            // or below API 16: yourView.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);

        }
    });
```

Comment: I just tried. Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work, either.

Comment: it should work. Maybe it's because of your code. You should post your code as well.